# How to read numbers in file and put them into multiple arrays based on separator?

Tags: matlab

Data sample:

```
1
2
3
-
4
5
-
6
7
8
```

I have a file with one number per line and there is a separator. How can I get an array like that:

```
output = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8]]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Read the file contents into int vector `fscanf(fid,'%d',[1 inf])` and skip one string `fscanf(fid,'%s', 1)`, then continue reading a vector and one string until end-of-file.

```
out = {};
fid = fopen('file.txt');
while ~feof(fid)
    out{end+1:end+1} = fscanf(fid,'%d',[1 inf]);
    fscanf(fid,'%s', 1);
end
fclose(fid);

out =
  1×3 cell array
    {[1 2 3]}    {[4 5]}    {[6 7 8]}
```